# Change behavior of click on desktop

Tags: finder, desktop, macos

Sometimes when I click on the desktop, Finder opens. How can I disable this in OS X 10.9?

For what it's worth, it was already happening in Mountain Lion.

Comment: This is not intended afaik. Are you sure that you are not clicking on a file?

Comment: @TrungNguyenChi: yes, I am. I just single click on an empty spot of the desktop.

Comment: I assume you mean a Finder _window_ opens, launching the default location of new finder windows (i.e. your home folder)? As I have noticed a worsened funky window bug across all applications since 10.8.3, it's possible this is the same bug, however, I typically have so many windows open including Finder windows, that I wouldn't normally be in an identical situation.

Comment: @NOTjust--user4304: no, Finder just comes to the top, showing whatever was open before...

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you didn't exit that finder window last time you exited logged out or shut down your mac.

If not that then you have some form of malware on your computer